# Map function not called on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to run an application on hadoop-1.0.1 and I noticed that the application doesn't enter in the map function. On hadoop local the application runs properly but on distributed hadoop the map function is not called.

I have this structure

```
Class Embed {

public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
          ........
     }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<LongWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
               ..........
        }
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        readArguments(args);
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Embed.class);
    conf.setJobName("embed");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    //conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(input));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(output));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);

}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the input path is valid for the server.  If there's no data there then the mapper won't be called since it's called once per record.

Comment: The input path is valid.